# Non-linear analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis

1) I am looking for a book which would give the proof of the following theorem(see below). I didn't find any book who does it:

- in infinite dimension (in Rockafellar Convex analysis book we are in finite dimension)
- considering the linear continuous application (written A or L in the following print screen) (I found for example the Fenchel duality theorem but doing it just with the sum, without considering the linear application. I have no ideas of the technical complexity of considering A.)

I know all the theorems I posted are intimately related so if I can find the proof of one of them it could be sufficient to prove the others.

2) More generally i would like to find a book who give the proofs of the pdf: https://www.ljll.math.upmc.fr/mathmodel/enseignement/polycopies/M2B003-AB.pdf
(so in the case the more general).

Thanks for your help!!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend "Techniques of Variational Analysis" by Borwein and Zhu, in particular Chapter 4.

The first Theorem can be found as Theorem 4.3.3 and the second one as Theorem 4.4.3.

Edit: The proofs concerning the facts in the linked pdf could be found in any serious book on functional analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I find the book quite pedagogic for such a math level

Answer (score 1):

The best result of the form you want are in "Convex Analysis in General Vector Spaces" by C Zalinescu

see also http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/5021

Comment: I have already heard about this book, thanks for your help